# Sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The Task is to find the Sum of the given function series, that is defined as: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$

I'm kinda lost, but at least i managed to take a few steps towards the solution.

Due to the fact, the given series is a series of functions, i need to determine if the series converges at all. And it does. I found out the Radius of Convergence, its $\lvert x \rvert < 1$

I think, the Sum must be determined somehow this way:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$

And here is, where im stuck. How do i calculate the Limit of Series of Functions like this?

**p.s.** the edits were only for improving language and latex

Comment: Hint, why don't you write out a few terms for n=0,1,2. You will recognize a geometric series where x is to be replaced by x^4. Try it out!

Comment: its  $(0+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^9}{9}+\frac{x^{13}}{13}+\frac{x^{17}}{17}\dots)$ and the first derivative is as shown below but i still cannot get the Connection to the given Problem. maybe there is some Kind of a missing link in my brain. What do i have to calculate in order to get the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By properties of power series, the function $f:x\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ on $(-1,1)$, and
$$
f^\prime(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{4n}
$$
Thus, since this last one is easy to compute,
$$
f^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^4}
$$
for all $x\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: Well, now we have the answer....wasn't a tip in the right direction a better move?

Comment: There is still one step to find the solution, since this is only $f^\prime$; furthermore, the hint "derive term-wise" is giving away basically as much.

Comment: But $\frac{1}{1-x^4}$ is not the Sum of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$ that i was looking for? ... otherwise, please give me a hint, on which topic do i have to read, in order to understand why.

Comment: It is its derivative. The question now boils down to how to compute $f$, knowing $f^\prime$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: To find f, knowing f' we Need to integrate f' ... because: $\int\limits_{a}^{b} f^{\prime}(x) = f(x)$ ... right?

Comment: Not exactly, but close:
in this case, as $f$ is continuous, $\int_{0}^{x} f^{\prime} = f(x)-f(0)=f(x) $

Comment: Are you sure about that? It seems to turn out for me, that this Integral isn't one of the easy things.  $\int_{0}^{x} f^{\prime} \frac{1}{1-x^4} = \frac{1}{2}\left(tan^{-1}(x) + coth^{-1}(x)\right)$ .. thats quite unconfortable

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "uncomfortable": this is a closed-form expression -- what did you expect?

Comment: Yes, but the argument of $f$ is the $x$ in the sum, __not__ $n$. $f(0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{0^{4n +1}}{4n +1}$...